# Broken thumbnails are displaying instead of product images in post object (field type) ACF

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, wordpress

I am displaying product images on product page using ACF. Only permalink and title is displaying and product pictures are not displaying instead of that broken thumbnails are displaying. My field type and return format is post object and here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<?php
$featured_posts = get_field('products_images');
if( $featured_posts ): ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $featured_posts as $featured_post ): 
    $permalink = get_permalink( $featured_post);
    $title = get_the_title( $featured_post);
    $image = get_field('products_images');
    ?>

<li>
    <?php
   
    if ( !empty($image) ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />

        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $permalink ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></a>
    </li>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you verified what $image actually contains yet, for example by `var_dump`-ing it?

Comment: It's a bit suspcious that it looks for a field called 'products_images' - ie plural. Is it returning say an array? Look to see how ACF has that field defined.